# Jupyter: pandas pretty describe function wrapped in if statement not possible?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I found this useful pandas describe function I can use like this:
[image: pandas describe function working]

My code is now cluttered with meta information and I wanted to introduce a debug version with debug meta information and one that just trains my NN. Just via a boolean switch. But I found some commands like pandas describe will not produce an output when wrapped in an if statement
[image: pandas describe function wrapped in if statement not working]

The only workaround I found so far is wrapping it in a print function. It results in an ugly but correct output
[image: working but ugly workaround]

Why is that or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display` and `HTML` to get what you want.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[3, 4]))

if True:
    display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate that helped. For me the solution was just to wrap it in display(my_var) but fair enough